# How to open same activity after clicked difference notifications

Tags: android, notifications

i spend a lot of time to resolve my problem. i have written a messenger client in android. my application receive income message and raise a notification. in notification bar i display each income message in a notification item. when click to notification item it will open a conversation activity to list all messages from the beginning until now. everything dose perfect but when i click another item in notification bar, nothing happen! (it must reload data for another conversation). This is my code to raise a notification:

```
private void showNotification(String message, Class activity, Message messageObject) {
        //Get the Notification Service
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence text =  message;//getText(R.string.service_started);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Intent callbackIntent = new Intent(context, activity);
        if(messageObject != null)
        {
            callbackIntent.putExtra("conversation", MessageManager.getProvider().getConversation(messageObject.getConversationId()));
        }
        //callbackIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        int myUniqueValue = new Random().nextInt();
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, myUniqueValue, callbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, messageObject.getFrom(), text, contentIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(messageObject.getFrom(), myUniqueValue, notification);
    }
```

This is code block to call showNotification function

```
showNotification(message.getBody(), ConversationActivity.class, messageObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite your efforts to supply a unique value, those `PendingIntent`s are all treated as the same by the system, so once you click one, the rest are rendered inert.

You'll need to add something distinguishing to `callbackIntent`; I suggest inventing a data URI that includes the conversation ID or something else that's guaranteed to be different for each notification (see [setData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setData%28android.net.Uri%29)).

Finally, I'd encourage you to try to collapse multiple notifications into one icon—you don't want to spam the user. See the [Notifications section in the Android Design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html), under "Stack your notifications".

Answer (score -1):

i changed my code and it work very well

```
private void showNotification(Context context, CharSequence contentTitle, CharSequence contentText, CharSequence notificationContent, Class activity, Conversation conversation) {
        //Get the Notification Service
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, notificationContent, System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Intent callbackIntent = new Intent(context, activity);
        if(conversation != null)
        {
            callbackIntent.putExtra("conversation", conversation);
        }
        callbackIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        int myUniqueValue = new Random().nextInt();
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, myUniqueValue, callbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(myUniqueValue, notification);
    }
```